# What are services and why add them in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I just started learning ASP.NET Core. Within the framework of the Web API template, there is a `Startup` class, in which the `ConfigureServices()` method is defined. Can someone explain in simple words what services it sets up, and why does it need them? Thanks!

Comment: Its for the Dependency Injection. Just google it and you will found dozen of explanations and examples.

Comment: `Services` = `some Dependencies/added pakages`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

ASP.NET Core uses [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) as a fundamental feature to manage dependencies throughout the framework. In order for the dependency injection framework to know *how* to resolve dependencies, these dependencies or *“services”* need to be configured first.

ASP.NET Core does this already for the very core services when you create the web host in your `Program.cs` but as you enable more features in your web application, you will need to add additional services to the application to opt into functionality.

For example `services.AddMvc()` adds the services required to enable the MVC functionality and middleware in the application. Or `services.AddAuthentication()` adds the services that are required to enable authentication in your application.

Since these functionalities are opt-in based and not enabled by default, the author of an application needs a way to control this. That is why the `ConfigureServices` method is there: Here, you can add the services you want to enable the functionality.

In addition, you can also use this to add *your own services* so that you can make use of dependency injection within the application as well; for example to resolve your own services within a controller.

Dependency injection is actually a rather complex topic, so I would suggest you to take a look at the [documentation on dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to see how it works and what you can do with it.

Comment: So, what is the difference between the `app.Usexxxx` in `Configure` method and the `services.AddXXX`?

Comment: @hguser `Add~` methods in `ConfigureServices` configure the dependency injection container by adding services or configurations. The `Use~` methods in the `Configure` method configure the ASP.NET Core *middleware pipeline*. They determine what happens with incoming requests and how and when they are handled by the middleware components (e.g. the authentication middleware, or the routing middleware).

Answer (score 7):

ConfigureServices has one parameter, of type IServiceCollection. IServiceCollection, this is a DI (Dependency Injection) container. Adding services to this container will make them available for dependency injection.  That means we can inject those services anywhere in our application. ConfigureServices is primarily for DI and setting up various library setup included for your project.

Comment: See: https://codingblast.com/asp-net-core-configureservices-vs-configure/

Answer (score 3):

> The `ConfigureServices` method is:
>
> - Optional.
> - Called by the host before the Configure method to configure the app's
>     services.
> - Where configuration options are set by convention.
>
> The typical pattern is to call all the `Add{Service}` methods and then
>      call all of the `services.Configure{Service}` methods. For example, see
>      [Configure Identity services][1].
>
> The host may configure some services before Startup methods are called. For more information, see The host.
>
> For features that require substantial setup, there are Add{Service} extension methods on `IServiceCollection`. A typical ASP.NET Core app registers services for Entity Framework, Identity, and MVC:
>
> ```
> public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
> {
>     services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
>         options.UseSqlServer(
>             Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
>     services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
>         .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
>         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
>
>
>     services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
>
>     // Add application services.
>     services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
>     services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
> }
> ```
>
> Adding services to the service container makes them available within the app and in the Configure method. The services are resolved via dependency injection or from `ApplicationServices`.

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.2#the-configureservices-method